Why is there a lot of space in one of my column names?
Why is there a bunch of blank space below TAVG in the column name?

I created this dataframe and the column name is formatted weirdly. Are my column names "DATE" and "TAVG" or "DATE" and "TAVG
"? I'm having issues referring back to these columns and the code is unable to find them.
EDIT: I figured it out, it's because the "DATE" column is actually an index. Once I moved it to a column, they lined up and I was able to use "DATE" as a column.

I think that is because of the groupby operation, but not sure

I figured it out, it's because the "DATE" column is actually an index. Once I moved it to a column, they lined up and I was able to use "DATE" as a column.
#Average temp by month
weather_data_monthly_avg = weather_data.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(weather_data['DATE'], freq="M"))['TAVG'].mean()
#Put output into dataframe
df_weather_monthly_avg = pd.DataFrame(weather_data_monthly_avg)
#Move DATE from index to column
df_weather_monthly_avg = df_weather_monthly_avg.reset_index()
df_weather_monthly_avg = df_weather_monthly_avg[['DATE','TAVG']]
df_weather_monthly_avg

    DATE    TAVG
0   2021-01 46.096774
1   2021-02 47.535714
2   2021-03 59.129032
3   2021-04 62.733333
4   2021-05 69.677419
5   2021-06 76.666667
6   2021-07 78.774194
7   2021-08 79.258065
8   2021-09 73.466667
9   2021-10 66.322581
10  2021-11 52.366667
11  2021-12 55.387097

